# Bootstrap button click event only fires on upper half

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button with no other styling than that provided by Bootstrap

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"
                ng-disabled = "svc.selectDisabled"
                ng-click="svc.chooseSelected()">Auswählen</button>
```

The click event only fires on the upper half of the button surface as indicated by the cursor hover.

[image: Cursor on upper half] [image: Cursor on lower half]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Try to inspect the element. See if the rendered position is same as appearing position. It might be some positioning inherited from parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Check css

open dev tools and hove the button to see the area that is taken up by the button itself. like the diagram below.

[image]

or use the select element button (in the red square)

[image]

and hover over the button. this will let you see if something is over the top of it.

If something is over the top then you need to set relative and give it a z-index. Or better, make sure to trim off things you don't need.

Comment: Thank you.  The placeholder for the modal body appears to be covering it.  I will give it a z-index and see if that works

Comment: Well, z-index doesn't solve the problem.  It is a Bootstrap modal dialog and the buttons are in the modal-header, but something seems to be pushing them outside of it.

Comment: Have you tried giving both a position that isn't static?

Comment: Yep, that's what I did.  I moved the buttons out from under.  Thanks again

Comment: No problem, best of luck.